# WPF MediaElement Opacity is not set after executing Storyline

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, opacity, doubleanimation

I'm using `DoubleAnimation` and `Storyboard` to control `Opacity` of `MediaElement`. The animation itself works fine, but if I call `Disappear` and `playVid` after several seconds, the `Opacity` of the `player` remains 0! What's the problem?

```
public void playVid(string source, bool isMainVid)
{
    player.Opacity = 1;
    player.Play(); //player.Opacity is 0 here!
}

public void Disappear()
{
    DoubleAnimation fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = 0,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
    };
    fadeOut.Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
        player.Stop();
    };
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(fadeOut);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeOut, player.Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOut, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
    storyboard.Begin(mainGrid, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace); //mainGrid is player's parent
}
```

Comment: Set the animation's FillBehavior to Stop.

Comment: @Clemens Now `Opacity` is reseted to the value before animation when it completes. To 1 after fading to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FillBehavior` equal to `Stop`, but also set the `Opacity` of your player to the final opacity value (in the `Completed` handler). Otherwise, it will be reset to its value before the animation.

```
var fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation
{
    To = 0,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)),
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
};

fadeOut.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    player.Stop();
    player.Opacity = 0;
};
```

See this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-set-a-property-after-animating-it-with-a-storyboard) for other approaches.